# Brace indexing error when using MATLAB cell2mat() function

Tags: matlab, plot, indexing

I can't understand why I'm suddenly getting an error even though I've used cell2mat in the same way for prior codes. The error reads

```
Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
Error in cell2mat
cellclass = class(c{1});
```

And the corresponding code is

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

parta = xlsread('C:\Users\Zahin\Desktop\Fall 2018\MEC 516\Lab 9\Data.xlsx',1,'A3:R15');
partb = xlsread('C:\Users\Zahin\Desktop\Fall 2018\MEC 516\Lab 9\Data.xlsx',2,'A3:K11');

a_rg = cell2mat(parta(:,1));
```

My goal is to turn these cells into column vectors so that I can use the plot function. When I do something like:

```
plot(parta(:,1),parta(:,2));
```

MATLAB will create a line plot that connects each point in the order of the array element index (i.e., (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) even if (x3,y3) would be closer to (x1,y1) in a linear fit). I can't understand why this occurs, but I assume its related to the fact that I can't convert the table arrays.

Comment: I presume `parta` is not a cell array. Did you examine it’s value?

Answer (score 2):

If you use **xlsread** with only 1 return argument as:

`num = xlsread(filename, sheet);`,

the return value will be numeric matrix, hence you cannot convert the numeric matrix using the cell2mat function. What you probably used before is:

`[num, txt, raw] = xlsread(filename, sheet);`,

which returns cell arrays for second and third return value, since `txt` will read all cells that contain only text data, and place it in cell matrix, and `raw` will read all data, and again place it in cell matrix, mixing numbers and character arrays.